# Java Bracket Notation?

Tags: java

In javascript you can reference an object's properties using either dot notation, or bracket notation.  This can be useful by using a string variable such as:

```
var myObject = { hello: "world" };
var prop = "hello";

// both will output "world".
console.log( myObject[ prop ] );
console.log( myObject.hello );
```

Is there a similar syntax in java to access an objects properties using a string variable, similar to javascript's bracket notation?

Comment: The closest thing to your answer would be via [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)), but this should probably not be advised. There is no direct analogue since Java is relatively strict on typing.

Comment: More important I think is the question is "why?". If it's just curiosity then reflection or using a normal hash map will do. If not we need a better context of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

No, there's not. About the closest thing there is would be using reflection, but that's clunky to say the least. You have to look up the `Field` and then get the instance's value for it.

```
Field property = myInstance.getClass().getDeclaredField("prop");
Object value = property.get(myInstance);
```

Not what you're looking for, I know, but it's the closest there is unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such syntax in Java, but there is an API ([reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)) that lets you do that, albeit in a less direct way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no similar syntax in java, or any direct way to do this.

java *does* provide a reflection API that allows you to query an object's properties/interface at runtime using `Strings` that represent e.g. an object's properties and methods.

You can also store (key, value) properties in a data structure such as a `HashMap`, mapping `Strings` to objects.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** I don't think there is any syntax like that in java.

**2.** But i would prefer using the `Key-Value` pair, and thats `Map`.

**3.** `Reflection API` that can be also used in this case.